# How to zip files in groovy not using ant?

Tags: groovy, zip

I need to zip files in a directory using groovy -- not using ant though.

I have tried out two versions of a code I found on the net.

1) If I comment out the whole InputStream section then zip file with all files is created. But the files are 0 size.

```
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

String zipFileName = "output.zip"  
String inputDir = "c:/temp"

ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName))

byte[] buf = new byte[1024]

new File(inputDir).eachFile() { file ->  
 println file.name.toString()
 println file.toString()

  output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.name.toString())) // Create the name of the entry in the ZIP

  InputStream input = file.getInputStream() // Get the data stream to send to the ZIP
  // Stream the document data to the ZIP
  int len;
  while((len = input.read(buf)) > 0){
    output.write(buf, 0, len);
    output.closeEntry(); // End of document in ZIP
  }
}  
output.close(); // End of all documents - ZIP is complete
```

2) If I tried to use this code then the files in the created zip file got incorrect size. Max size is 1024.

```
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream  
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry  
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel  


String zipFileName = "output.zip"  
String inputDir = "c:/temp"

ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName))

new File(inputDir).eachFile() { file ->  
  zipFile.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()))  
  def buffer = new byte[1024]  
  file.withInputStream { i ->  
    l = i.read(buffer)  
    // check wether the file is empty  
    if (l > 0) {  
      zipFile.write(buffer, 0, l)  
    }  
  }  
  zipFile.closeEntry()  
}  
zipFile.close()
```

Comment: @tim_yates: because we use groovy in our product and I am not sure if I would need to somehow import/include ant jar. I wanted as generic solution as possible. In fact I hoped someone would pointed out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Ant is bundled with groovy so you can use antbuilder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the way to get InputStream was good. I could create one using *new FileInputStream(file);*

Improved from first example, uses Java 7

```
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream

String zipFileName = "c:/output.zip"
String inputDir = "c:/temp"

ZipOutputStream output = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName))


new File(inputDir).eachFile() { file ->
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        return
    }
    println file.name.toString()
    println file.toString()

    output.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.name.toString())) // Create the name of the entry in the ZIP

    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);

    // Stream the document data to the ZIP
    Files.copy(input, output);
    output.closeEntry(); // End of current document in ZIP
    input.close()
}
output.close(); // End of all documents - ZIP is complete
```

Comment: Your code works smoothly. Yes, I do know that implementation of InputStream was not good, I was hoping that someone could correct it. But the main think was to create zip file :-)

Answer (score 0):

based on your own coding, just omit this line.

```
output.closeEntry();
```