# How do I create a Zip task in gradle that produces more than one Zip file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, zip

Is it possible?
I need to create one zip for each sub-folder, but the code I have is always overwriting

Comment: We can't see the "code you have"; IIRC a single zip task creates a single zip file but tasks can depend on one another.

Comment: Assuming you're using Groovy (not Kotlin) for Gradle, you could just do it programmatically with a regular (non-Zip) task...  Example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810979/how-to-zip-files-in-groovy-not-using-ant

Comment: show the code you fail with and provide more details

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to assume it's Groovy given the tags on the question.  The Zip task is only going to produce a single zip file.  I'm going to assume you have some directory you want to produce a single zip file for each subfolder of that target directory.  The most straight forward way is to just write the code that does this using Groovy:

```
task subfolderZip {
   File target = file("${projectDir}/path/to/folder")
   inputs.dir target
   outputs.dir "${buildDir}/zips"
   doLast {
      target.listFiles({ it.isDirectory() } as FileFilter).each { File sub ->
          File zipFile = file( "${buildDir}/zips/${sub.name}.zip" )
          if(!zipFile.getParentFile().exists()) zipFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()
          new ZipOutputStream( zipFile.newOutputStream() ).withCloseable { zip ->
             sub.eachFileRecurse( FileType.FILE ) { f ->
                 ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry( f.absolutePath.subString( sub.absolutePath.length() ) )
                 zip.putEntry( entry )
                 f.withInputStream { inStream ->
                    zip << inStream
                 }
                 zip.closeEntry()
             }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

So that is pretty straightforward, but here are some caveats.  The task is going to execute every time regardless if it's already built this stuff.  I've tried to mitigate that by declaring the inputs and outputs of the task.  It might need to know about all of the zips it should produce which means a little more code that would execute dynamically during build initialization.

You could do this with Zip task, but you'd be creating Zip tasks dynamically based on the subfolders the inside your target folder.  Again this would mean writing code that runs each time the `build.gradle` file is evaluated.  Not impossible, but best done using a plugin rather than doing that in your build file.